# mysql.exe in CMD just started giving "this app can't run on your pc" error

Tags: mysql

I'm in the process of importing a database into MySQL in WAMP. I've been doing database imports for the past couple of days fine.

I'm running Windows 10, and CMD as administrator.

Today the same import command pops up the "this app can't run on your pc". I thought it might have been an issue with the database itself, so tried just entering mysql.exe and hitting enter, but it gives the same error. If I try double clicking mysql.exe in bin, it gives the same error.

If I try to run the MySQL console from WAMP, I get the following error:

Could not execute run action: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
Action : Run
Filename: c:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql8.0.21/bin/mysql.exe
Parameters: -u %MysqlUser% -p

I tried a good old fashioned restart - but no go.

mysql.exe is showing a file size of 0kb

Any idea what's going on here?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, this issue is the result of corrupt files or using incompatible applications with the machine. So in your case, I think the MySql might be corrupted. You may try the following.

- Try using workbench
- Install another Wamp

Comment: Thanks Lewis. mysql.exe is showing a file size of 0kb - does that change your recommended course of action. Can I just find an installation of mysql (same version) and copy over and replace the mysql.exe file?

Comment: Nevermind - I installed the same version of WAMP on my other Windows 10 machine, copied over the mysql.exe to replace the 0kb one, and it's working again. I'm curious - why would the mysql.exe suddenly become empty like that though? Any ideas?

Comment: as I said earlier your MySQL might be corrupted so that is the main cause.